# Script to remove diagnostic files with specific extension

Tags: python, shell, delete-file

I have time dependent diagnostic output files such as

```
output1.1
output1.2
output1.3
.
.
.
output1.998
output1.999
output1.1000

output2.1
output2.2
output2.3
.
.
.
output2.998
output2.999
output2.1000
```

How do I go about removing all files greater than some timestep, for instance t=500?

I expect there are multiple ways of doing this, so I am open to multiple suggestions.

Comment: You have tagged this with both "python" and "shell". Does this mean that you are after solutions in either?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

os.chdir(path)
for file in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            if int(file.split(".")[1]) >= 500:         
            os.remove(file)
        except (OSError, ValueError):
            #couldnt remove the path, non time postfix path or os error
```

Comment: You might want to filter the file list so that it only processes file starting `output.`. Hopefully it will raise a `ValueError` on the first filename with a non-numeric extension and terminate before it does too much unintentional deletion.

Comment: @alaniwi  no problem i can handle this. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3):

Something like this in shell:

```
for file in output*.*; do
  if [ "${file##*.}" -gt 500 ]; then
    rm "$file"
  fi
done
```

`${variable##pattern}` removes the longest match of *pattern* from the beginning of the variables contents. In this case it gives you just the number after the last period of the filename.

Version that calls `rm` fewer times if that's a concern:

```
for file in output*.*; do
  if [ "${file##*.}" -gt 500 ]; then
    printf "%s\0" "$file"
  fi
done | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Well it certainly works (albeit with potentially a lot of separate invocations of `rm`). Could you please include some words of explanation about what `${file##*.}` does?

Comment: Thans Shawn. Also, I edited the question because I realized I did not make clear that I have multiple diagnostics at each time.

Comment: @alaniwi Added.

Comment: @js16 Just needs a tweak to the file glob. See edit.

Comment: @Shawn Great, thank you. Your solution also has the distinct advantage that it is the only one of the five solutions offered so far that actually bothers to check whether the filename starts with `output` before it deletes the file!

Answer (score 0):

If all your files are in one folder this would work. Change mypath to youe path.

```
from os import listdir, remove
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = 'D:\Files\Python\Output'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for f in onlyfiles:
    if int(f.split('.')[1]) > 500:
        remove(mypath+'\\'+f)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os

files = [x for x in os.listdir() if int(x.split('.')[1]) > 500]

for file in files:
  os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

In python you can try the following:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('.')
for name in p.glob('*.[0-9]*'):
    ext = name.suffix
    if int(ext) > 500:
     name.unlink()
```